# Powershell: как решить проблему с знаками вопроса вместо русских букв?

Tags: кодировка, powershell

Получаю по API JSON результат. Но русские буквы отображаются в виде знаков вопроса.
Есть идеи, товарищи? Спасибо заранее

Что запускаю:

```
$url2 = "http://********/rooms?limit=3&access_token=******"
$rres = Invoke-WebRequest -Method GET -Uri $url2 -ContentType "application/json;charset=utf-8" | ConvertFrom-Json
$Lmres = $rres.chunk
Write-Host $Lmres[0].Content
```

Получаю:

```
@{body=???? ??????) ; msgtype=m.text}
@{body=??????????????; msgtype=m.text}
@{body=??????????; msgtype=m.text}
```

Кодировку запроса к json менял на win-1251, ничего не изменилось.

Answer (score 1):

В данной строке:

```
$rres = Invoke-WebRequest -Method GET -Uri $url2 -ContentType "application/json;charset=utf-8"
```

вы задаёте не кодировку отклика, а кодировку запроса. Нужно менять кодировку уже возвращаемых данных. Не могу сэмулировать именно ваш запрос, поскольку адрес неизвестен, но выглядеть это должно как-то так:

```
$rus_result =  [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding('windows-1251').GetString([Byte[]]$your_result)
```

или то же самое, но с utf-8 вместо windows-1251

Comment: Добрый день. Говорит следующее: Не удается преобразовать аргумент "bytes", со значением: "???? ??????) ", для "GetString" в тип "System.Byte[]": "Не удается 
преобразовать значение "???? ??????) " в тип "System.Byte[]". Ошибка: "Не удается преобразовать значение "???? ??????) " в ти
п "System.Byte". Ошибка: "Входная строка имела неверный формат."""

Comment: @technor логично, нужно преобразование ([Byte[]]), сейчас дополню ответ